# Align imageview in layouts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95g0p.png)

Hi guys, Im kinda noob in android studios layout..I just want to make the button be aligned to the description text, but cant find the code, can you plz help me out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@color/gray">

    <!-- The dimensions are based on some experimentation -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/button"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="I'm a button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the layout below .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="I'm a button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**PS:-** Try to move on to `ConstraintsLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.